# Как прикрепить событие к множеству динамически созданным элементам?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код где динамически создаются два button элемента

`const button1 = $('button.picker-1');
const  button2 = $('button.picker-2');`

Нужно динамически прикрепить к ним свойство click, для одного элемента работает код

```
$('#register-form').on('click', button1, function() {
    console.log('working');
});
```

Как  прикрепить событие сразу к двум динамически созданным  элементам button1, button2 ?

Если есть ответ и на javascript тоже буду рад посмотреть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ко всем создаваемым элементам добавьте общий класс, например, `.picker`, после чего используйте его при регистрации обработчика

```
$('#register-form').on('click', ".picker", function() {
    console.log('working');
});
```